# Django queryset : group_by and compare latest value

Tags: django

I have a model which stores date ranges of people associated with an association.

So the data is stored like this:

```
person    |    start_date    |    end_date
Person1   |    2014-05-01    |   2014-10-20
Person1   |    2015-01-10    |   2015-05-12 *I want this entry
Person2   |    2012-11-11    |   2013-01-02
Person2   |    2014-02-12    |   NULL
Person3   |    2015-02-12    |   2015-08-01 *I want this entry
```

How can I get only the members who have left the association? (the end_date of the last date range is greater or equal of the start_date of the last date range).

**The model:**

```
class Period(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you need, but you can find it in django queryset api.

Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__range=(start_date, end_date))
Entry.objects.exclude(pub_date__gt=datetime.date(2015, 5, 12))

Comment: Basically, I just want to get the members that do not have NULL values in any of the "start_date" and "end_date" fields.